# Data Visualization & Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization

Preprocess the data and see the results after and before preprocessing(Report as accuracy)

Draw the following charts:

- Corelation chart Heatmap chart
- Missing Values Heatmap chart
- Line chart/ scatter chart for Country Vs Purchased, Age Vs Purchased and Salary Vs Purchased

```
Country Age Salary  Purchased
France  44  72000   No
Spain   27  48000   Yes
Germany 30  54000   No
Spain   38  61000   No
Germany 40          Yes
France  35  58000   Yes
Spain       52000   No
France  48  79000   Yes
Germany 50  83000   No
France  37          Yes
France      18888   No
Spain   17  67890   Yes
Germany     12000   No
Spain   38  98888   No
Germany 50          Yes
France  35  58000   Yes
Spain       12345   No
France  23          Yes
Germany 55  78456   No
France      43215   Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's hard to understand from scatter plot like Country vs Purchased.  Three country of your list somehow purhcased. It can be helpful to do heatmap [here](https://dev.to/tomoyukiaota/visualizing-the-patterns-of-missing-value-occurrence-with-python-46dj)

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#read csv using panda

df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
copydf = df

#before data preprocessing
print(copydf)

#fill nan value with average of age and salary

df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(df['Age'].mean(axis=0))
df['Salary '] = df['Salary'].fillna(df['Salary'].mean(axis=0))

#after data preprocessing
print(df)

plt.figure(1)

#  Country Vs Purchased
plt.subplot(221)
plt.scatter(df['Country'], df['Purchased'])
plt.title('Country vs Purchased')
plt.grid(True)


#  Age Vs Purchased
plt.subplot(222)
plt.scatter(df['Age'], df['Purchased'])
plt.title('Age vs Purchased')
plt.grid(True)


# Salary Vs Purchased
plt.subplot(223)
plt.scatter(df['Salary'], df['Purchased'])
plt.title('Salary vs Purchased')
plt.grid(True)

plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.92, bottom=0.08, left=0.10, right=0.95, hspace=0.75,
                    wspace=0.5)

plt.show()
```